# Google SQL Join ON STRING and ARRAY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to join 2 tables together, one table has an id the other has an array of id's. The ID from table 1 will be contained in on of these arrays.

I've tried a few different methods, one of which involves converting the array to a long integer and then seeing if the id is in that long integer (this has not worked for me)

here is one as an example -

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_1 as d
ON d.id LIKE '%ARRAY_TO_STRING(c.ids, "")%'
```

I'm not sure if this is even a possibility within Google SQL. Any response or recommendations would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ...
FROM `project.dataset.table1` t1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT ...
  FROM `project.dataset.table1` t1
  JOIN `project.dataset.table2` t2
  ON id IN UNNEST(ids)
)
USING(id)
```

You can test, play with above using some dummy data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table1` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 11 a, 12 b UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 21, 22 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 31, 32 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 41, 42
), `project.dataset.table2` AS (
  SELECT [1, 3, 7] ids, 11 x, 12 y UNION ALL
  SELECT [2, 3, 8], 21, 22 UNION ALL
  SELECT [33, 6, 9], 31, 32
)

SELECT id, t1.a, t1.b, ids, x, y
FROM `project.dataset.table1` t1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM `project.dataset.table1` t1
  JOIN `project.dataset.table2` t2
  ON id IN UNNEST(ids)
)
USING(id)
```

with output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unnest` in the `on` clause:

```
select . . .
from table1 t1 left join
     (table2 t2 cross join
      unnest(t2.ids) t2_id
     )
     on t1.id = t2_id
```